# ffmpeg Как узнать PID для AVPacket?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

`PID` это идентификатор (13 бит) в MPEG-TS потоке (стриме), присваиваемый каждому элементарному транспортному пакету (ЭТП).

Библиотека ffmpeg при чтении выдает структуры `AVPacket`, которые содержат данные (payload), передаваемые в этих самых ЭТП.
Понадобилось узнать `PID` этих самых пакетов. Как это сделать?

Comment: Это вам надо лезть в демуксер mpegts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уникальный идентификатор медиа-пакетов (`PID`) стрима в библиотеке `ffmpeg` находится в структуре `AVStream`, в поле `id` (AVStream::id).